# Regex: Perform operations on matched groups

Tags: java, regex, sed

I have data in file which is like:

```
...
Position(123)
...
Position(234)
...
```

I want to update this file like:

```
...
Position(1230)
...
Position(2340)
...
```

I can do this using Java. Like:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexGroupOperation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] inputLines = new String[5];
        inputLines[0] = "Some Random Text";
        inputLines[1] = "Position(789)";
        inputLines[2] = "Some More Random Text";
        inputLines[3] = "Position(123)";
        inputLines[4] = "Position(456)";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Position\\(([0-9]+)\\)");
        for (String line : inputLines) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
            if (m.matches()) {
                System.out.println("Position(" + (Integer.valueOf(m.group(1)) * 10) + ")");
            } else {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I am capturing the portion of the string (group) on which I want to perform the operation. Then updating that group with the desired result.

I want to do the same using `sed`. Is it possible to perform the operation on matched group and then use the result in substitution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk -F 'Position\\(' 'NF>1{gsub(/.*/, "Position(" $2*10 ")")} 1' file
...
Position(1230)
...
Position(2340)
...
```

Comment: It is replacing everything which has only `)` but `Position(` does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below awk command.

```
$ awk -F[\(\)] '/[0-9]+/{var=$2;$2=var*10; print $1"("$2")"}!/[0-9]/' file
...
Position(1230)
...
Position(2340)
...
```

Comment: Multiplying by 10 is just as example. It could be any simple arithmetic operation.

Comment: it works for any number. Just replace the 10 in the above command with the number you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/^Position([0-9]*/&0/' YourFile
```

If it is "just" adding a `0` in number of the *Position(...)* line